# how to configure embedded jetty + webjars

Tags: runtime, jetty, webjars

I have a project that runs embedded jetty server. 
Also, i have angularjs-1.2.12.jar in project's dependencies.

How do I configure jetty, to expose files from META-INF/resources. 
I tried to do the following:

```
    ResourceHandler resource_handler = new ResourceHandler();
    resource_handler.setDirectoriesListed(true);
    resource_handler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{ "index.html" });
    resource_handler.setBaseResource(Resource.newClassPathResource("/"));

    Server server = new Server(8080);
    server.setHandler(resource_handler);
```

But only files from target/classes are exposed.

Thank you.

UPD: solved

```
    ResourceHandler resource_handler = new ResourceHandler() {
        @Override
        public Resource getResource(String path)
                throws MalformedURLException {
            Resource resource = Resource.newClassPathResource(path);
            if (resource == null || !resource.exists()) {
                resource = Resource.newClassPathResource("META-INF/resources" + path);
            }
            return resource;
        }
    };
    resource_handler.setDirectoriesListed(true);
    resource_handler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{"index.html"});
    resource_handler.setResourceBase("/");
    server.setHandler(resource_handler);
```

Comment: What version of Jetty are you using?

Comment: It looks like the solution might expose all resources on the classpath to be served as static assets.  If so that could be a big security loophole.  This is why the default with Servlet 3 is to only do this for `META-INF/resources` prefixed paths.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and after looking all over, your solution was the best. But as pointed out by James Ward in comments, it poses a security issue. Here is my solution, building on yours:

```
public class MyResourceHandler extends ResourceHandler {
    @Override
    public Resource getResource(String path) {
        Resource resource = Resource.newClassPathResource("META-INF/resources" + path);
        if(resource == null) resource = super.getResource(path);
        return resource;
    }
}
```

As pointed out [here](https://github.com/perwendel/spark/issues/316), `ResourceHandler` is somewhat obsolete. I actually implemented this solution by extending `DefaultServlet` instead.